The crash occurs when using wstring_convert to convert binary data to UTF-16
I want to perform the following operation on the string pointed to by Name ID 19 in the "name" table of this TTF file, but it crashes.

All other strings work fine. Why is this happening?
The font file is seguiemj.ttf.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <codecvt>
#include <memory>
#include <locale>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> data = {
        0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDE, 0x02, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDE, 0x0D, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDE, 0x2D, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDC, 0x81,
        0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDC, 0x4D, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDC, 0x8B, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDC, 0x31, 0xD8, 0x3E, 0xDD, 0x89,
        0xD8, 0x3C, 0xDF, 0x3A, 0xD8, 0x3C, 0xDF, 0x32, 0xD8, 0x3C, 0xDF, 0x53, 0xD8, 0x3C, 0xDF, 0x55,
        0xD8, 0x3C, 0xDF, 0x82, 0xD8, 0x3C, 0xDF, 0xF0, 0xD8, 0x3C, 0xDF, 0xE0, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDE, 0x84,
        0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDE, 0x92, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDE, 0xEB, 0xD8, 0x3D, 0xDE, 0xCD
    };

    std::cout << data.size() << std::endl;

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
    const std::u16string u16str = converter.from_bytes(
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data()),
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data() + data.size())
    );

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converterUtf8;
    std::string nameString = converterUtf8.to_bytes(u16str);

    std::cout << nameString << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


This piece of code converterUtf8.to_bytes(u16str) will crash.
My logic might be a bit off, but I really do want to understand why writing it this way causes a crash.

Presumably the code is throwing an exception which you are failing to catch, or have you accounted for that?

Not what you are asking about, just my opinion, but the standard libraries Unicode stuff is such a god awful mess that you are better off coding it yourself.

Can you please try to create a proper [mre] to show us? And also show us the actual "error"/"crash" message you get.

Are you sure of the byte-ordering in data? Big-endian? Little-endian? See std::codecvt_mode As written the conversion mode presumes Big-endian.

@john I added a picture of rushing, and I didn't understand the meaning of this error.

@Someprogrammerdude I modified the code example, and now this can be run directly.

I believe David has nailed your issue.  You have inserted your sequence at an odd byte boundary.  The final character before your insert should be "2E 00".  Are you trying to get U+DE3D or U+3DD8?

@DavidC.Rankin These data come from the file of Seguiemj.ttf, and the TTF format files are Big-endian.

@TimRoberts Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean, but this data is 76 bytes, which is an even number, and I don't think it should be a problem. This question seems to involve the Surrogate Pair.

From this to_bytes reference: "If this wstring_convert object was constructed without a user-supplied wide-error string, throws std::range_error on conversion failure."

@Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much, I actually forgot about this site.

The strings in TrueType files are stored big-endian.  That means the most significant bytes come first.  Thus, the string you show has the glyphs D83D, DE02, D83D DE0D.  However, the machine you're testing on is little-ending, so the most significant byte comes second.  If you hope to decode it from bytes, you will need to SWAP the byte pairs, as in { 0x3D, 0xD8, 0x02, 0xDE, 0x3D, 0xD8, ...}.

@TimRoberts Ok thanks, I probably know the problem, this data is really not in the standard UTF-8 format, so it causes the wstring_convert to crash, and the solution is either to pass a placeholder character to the constructor of the wstring_convert and use it when the conversion fails, or use try catch. Thank you for your series of answers, thank you very much.

I think you need to start one byte earlier, i.e. 0x2e should be the first byte and the 0x00 right after your selection, too (or leave the 0xCD out?). At least the conversion succeeds with these changes.

@ChristianHalaszovich I probably know the problem, this data is really not in the standard UTF-8 format, so it causes the wstring_convert to crash, and the solution is either to pass a placeholder character to the constructor of the wstring_convert and use it when the conversion fails, or use try catch. Thank you for your series of answers, thank you very much

The problem has been solved, thank you.

Of course it's not in UTF-8 format.  It's UTF-16.  Things go 16 bits at a time, not 8 bits.

@ChristianHalaszovich This can really solve the problem, but it is not quite in line with business logic. I really appreciate it．
